# How a System.Configuration.Install.Installer instance can get the destination folder?

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation, setup-project

When my `ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer` is called by the Setup project the current path is `c:\windows\system32`. How can I get the path where the application is being installed without hard coding this to the project ? (the destination path is something like `c:\program files\[manufacturer]\[service name]`)

Comment: By curiosity, what are you trying to achieve with the destination path in the projectinstaller? Just curious

Comment: My Windows Service project don't know its own name, by design, so I can reuse it to host many different WCF services. But to run multiple instances of it, it needs to get a different name for each instance. The best name is the folder name where it is installed.

Comment: If I can get the folder name, I can give a proper name to the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is perfectly answered by the method described in the link below:

[How to make a System.Configuration.Install.Installer to get a variable from the Setup project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066048/how-to-make-a-system-configuration-install-installer-to-get-a-variable-from-the-s/2070876#2070876)

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: It will work if the assembly that contains the installer is in the application's folder which is usually the case.